# What's the difference between [physics] and [mathematical-physics]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

What's the difference between the [[physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics)] and [[mathematical-physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics)] tags?  Are they similar enough that we shouldn't have both?

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/center-of-mass-of-an-n-hemisphere doesn't need physics/mathematical-physics at all, does it?

Comment: center of mass is a physics concept, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Retaging all current `mathematical-physics` into `physics` should be OK, I think.

Answer (score 2):

They bring to mind different things to me.  "Physics" probably means something like quantum mechanics, while mathematical-physics probably means something like Chern-Simons Theory or the 2-dimensional Ising model.  Basically "Physics" means questions that are actually of interest to physicists, while "mathematical physics" is usually about *mathematical* results which are inspired by (but don't directly involve) physics.  But given the existence of MO, I doubt there will be many "mathematical-physics" questions here that aren't "physics" and so there's probably no harm in merging.  At MO I'd be against merging.

Comment: Is there a discernable difference in the questions currently tagged with one versus the other?

Comment: that's why I suggest retaging current mathematical-physics into physics, and not merging them — maybe we'll have real mathematical-physics some day